# Symfony 2 - flush in postUpdate fire preUpdate event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I detected this problem "thanks" to an exception I got:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to
Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs::__construct() 
must be an array, null given, called in 
/.../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 804 
and defined in
/.../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.php line 28
```

I am working on a project that requieres a specific logic:
When the `order` field in entity `book` is modified, I need to update field `books_order_modified_at` in the parent entity `bookstore` (this field allows me to know whether the order of books in a bookstore was changed).

I decided to do it in an event listener since there are many places in the code that might change the order of books.

I didn't find any way to update a related entity from `preUpdate` event, so I have a private field in the listener class which I use to tell the `postUpdate` event to update the relevant `bookstore` entity.

My problem is that when I do so the `preUpdate` event of the `book` entity is fired.
When I check the change-set it contains only the `modified_at` field, but it has the same value before and after.

If someone has another idea how to solve the problem - great.

If not - any idea how can I prevent the `preUpdate` event from being fired when the flush is called in teh `postUpdate` event??

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, actually I solved my problem using real-time server (node.js) so I no longer looking for a solution for this. However, if you have any, it will be interesting to see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this is a problem from doctrine [Doctrine Issue DDC-2726](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3468). Solved it by adding a clear call on the entity manager after the flush in the listener so the 3-rd argument to that constructor, which is actually the entityChangeSets, will be re-written.

Comment: How do you make a "clear call on the entity manager, can you describe that? Thanks!

Comment: "$args->getEntityManager()->clear();" Simply calling the clear method of the entity manager.

Comment: Thanks, I need to look into this, to really understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi, Calin! Can you provide us with some sample code so we can see where exactly you do perform the clear() call? Multumesc anticipat!

Answer (score 1):

What about updating the `modified_at` within your entities and let doctrine handle it? You would change your setOrder method in your book to update the BookOrder entity like this:

```
class Book {
    public function setOrder($order) {
        // modify book
        $this->bookOrder->updateModifiedAt();
    }
}
```

Of course your BookOrder would have to implement modifiedAt:

```
class BookOrder {
    public function updateModifiedAt() {
        $this->modifiedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

If you use other classes for your Datetime, you of course have to change this code!

Doctrine should recognize that BookOrder has changed and should update it without any need to use a event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use Timestampable extension for Doctrine from [DoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle).

By using it you don't need to set `created_at` or `modified_at` values. This extension does it automatically. Even it can set `modified_at` only when specific fields were modified. See [example](http://gediminasm.org/article/timestampable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2#entity-mapping).

I think you are writing something like this extension. So, you don't need to do that because this is already done :)

Comment: My problem is that the timestampable field which I want to update is of another entity, not of the entity which is modified. It is a nice extension, but I think that in my case it won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this. Trying to use `preupdate` to modify child elements caused the same error. In the end, my solution to simply update the children belonging to the parent. No explicit call to `flush` required.

```
/**
 * Update expiry dates for all runners belonging to a campaign
 *
 * @param $runners
 * @param $expiryDate
 */
private function updateCampaignRunners($runners, $expiryDate){
    foreach($runners as $runner){
        $runner->setExpiresAt($expiryDate);
        $this->getModelManager()->update($runner);
    }
}

/**
 * Post update and persist lifecycle callback
 *
 * @param Campaign $campaign
 */
private function postAction(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $runnerExpire = $this->getForm()->get("runnerExpire")->getData();
    if($runnerExpiryDate && $campaign->getRunners()){
        $this->updateCampaignRunners($campaign->getRunners(), $runnersExpiryDate);
    }
}
```